# Error al cargar un recyclerview con volley en fragments

Tags: android-fragment, volley, android-recyclerview

Estoy realizando una aplicacion que carga datos en un RecyclerView de un archivo Json con Volley en fragments , al correr la aplicacióny dirigirme al fragment Talleres se cierra la aplicacion.

Este es el error

```
05-20 03:23:35.752 19023-19023/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.conecit.angelo.conecit2018, PID: 19023
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.android.volley.Request com.android.volley.RequestQueue.add(com.android.volley.Request)' on a null object reference
    at com.conecit.angelo.conecit2018.fragments.TalleresFragment.cargardatos(TalleresFragment.java:72)
    at com.conecit.angelo.conecit2018.fragments.TalleresFragment.onCreateView(TalleresFragment.java:61)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2346)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1428)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1759)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1827)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2596)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2383)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2338)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2245)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:703)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:743)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5659)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:822)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:712)
```

Este es el Fragment.

```
public class TalleresFragment extends Fragment implements Response.Listener<JSONObject>,Response.ErrorListener {
RecyclerView recyclerTalleres;
ArrayList<DatosTalleres> listaTalleres;
ProgressDialog progres;
RequestQueue request;
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest;



public TalleresFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_talleres, container, false);
    showToolbar(getResources().getString(R.string.tab_talleres),false,view);
    recyclerTalleres=view.findViewById(R.id.talleresRecycler);
    recyclerTalleres.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getContext()));
    recyclerTalleres.setHasFixedSize(true);

    cargardatos();
    return view;
}

private void cargardatos() {

    progres=new ProgressDialog(getContext());
    progres.setMessage("Consultando Datos");
    progres.show();
    String url="http://conecit.pe/talleres.json";
    jsonObjectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null,this,this);
    request.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"no se pudo conectar"+error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    System.out.println();
    progres.hide();
    Log.d("Error: ",error.toString());

}

@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    DatosTalleres talleres=null;
    JSONArray json=response.optJSONArray("taller");
    try{
        for (int i=0;i<json.length();i++){
            talleres =new DatosTalleres();
            JSONObject jsonObject=null;
            jsonObject=json.getJSONObject(i);

            talleres.setTituloTaller(jsonObject.optString("tituloTaller"));
            talleres.setPonenteTaller(jsonObject.optString("ponenteTaller"));
            talleres.setDescripcionTaller(jsonObject.optString("descripcionTaller"));
            talleres.setDuracionTaller(jsonObject.optString("duracionTaller"));
            talleres.setPrecioTaller(jsonObject.optString("precioTaller"));
            talleres.setImagenTalleres(jsonObject.optString("imagenTaller"));
            talleres.setFotoPonente(jsonObject.optString("fotoPonente"));
            listaTalleres.add(talleres);

        }
        progres.hide();

        TalleresAdapterRecyclerview adapter = new TalleresAdapterRecyclerview(listaTalleres,getActivity(),getContext());

    }catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"No se puede conectar"+e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }


}


public void showToolbar(String tittle, boolean upButton, View view){
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(tittle);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(upButton);

}
```

}

Este es el adaptador

```
public class TalleresAdapterRecyclerview extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TalleresAdapterRecyclerview.Talleresviewholder> {
private ArrayList<DatosTalleres> listaTalleres;
private Activity activityTaller;
private Context context;
private RequestQueue request;

public TalleresAdapterRecyclerview(ArrayList<DatosTalleres> listaTalleres, Activity activityTaller, Context context) {
    this.listaTalleres = listaTalleres;
    this.context=context;
    this.activityTaller = activityTaller;
    request=Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Talleresviewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview_talleres,parent,false);
    RecyclerView.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    return new Talleresviewholder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Talleresviewholder holder, int position) {
    holder.tituloTalleresCard.setText(listaTalleres.get(position).getTituloTaller());
    holder.ponenteTallerCard.setText(listaTalleres.get(position).getPonenteTaller());
    holder.duracionTalleresCard.setText(listaTalleres.get(position).getDuracionTaller());
    holder.precioTallerCard.setText(listaTalleres.get(position).getPrecioTaller());
    //Picasso.with(activityTaller).load(listaTalleres.get(position).getImagenTalleres()).into(holder.imagentalleresCard);

    //holder.imagentalleresCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        //@Override
        //public void onClick(View v) {
           // Intent i = new Intent(activityTaller, DetailsTaller1.class);

            //if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
               // Explode explode = new Explode();
                //explode.setDuration(1000);
                //activityTaller.getWindow().setExitTransition(explode);
                //activityTaller.startActivity(i,
                   //     ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activityTaller,v,activityTaller.getString(R.string.transition_imagentalleres)).toBundle());

            //}else{
              //  activityTaller.startActivity(i);
            //}

        //}
   // });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listaTalleres.size();
}

public class Talleresviewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private ImageView imagentalleresCard;
    private TextView tituloTalleresCard,ponenteTallerCard,duracionTalleresCard,precioTallerCard;

    public Talleresviewholder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        imagentalleresCard             =(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagentalleresCard);
        tituloTalleresCard       =(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tituloTalleresCard);
        ponenteTallerCard        =(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ponenteTallerCard);
        duracionTalleresCard        =(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.duracionTalleresCard);
        precioTallerCard =(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.precioTallerCard);
    }
}
```

}

Me podrían ayudar, por favor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que no estas declarando `request`, es decir, es `null`, que es instancia de `RequestQueue` en el `Fragment`. Por lo que en el metodo, `cargardatos()` estas haciendo:

```
request.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Esto causa:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'com.android.volley.Request
>   com.android.volley.RequestQueue.add(com.android.volley.Request)' on a
>   null object reference

En el adapter haces esto: `request = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);`

Por lo que pienso que en el `Fragment` deberías hacer algo así, por ejemplo:

```
request = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
```

antes de llamar el método `cargardatos();` en el `onCreateView`.

Comment: muchas gracias , ya solucione el problema

Comment: Si te sirvió puedes marcar la respuesta como aceptada (debajo del contador de votos hay una flecha de aceptación). Saludos.

Comment: Hola , esa misma lista lo puedo almacenar en sharedpreferences para tener datos sin conexion?

Comment: @Angelotapullimadelaguila Si puedes almacenarlo. Pero al final tendras un objetivo tipo clave-valor, algo parecido a un hashmap, por lo que si quieres lograr persistencia de datos de una manera organizada y tienes experiencias con querys y bases de datos te recomiendo implementar: [SQLite para Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage?hl=es-419#db) puedes ver mas ejemplos aqui: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite#java